# Growing tabs and hover with bigger height

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, trying to make a hover higher than standart dark background in navigation tabs.

This works fine with "sliding doors" technique + sprite.
But it is neccessary to reconstruct a code with HTML 5 and CSS 3.

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <ul class="reset">
      <li class="current"><a href="index.html">home page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">technology</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">network</a></li>
      <li><a href="contacts.html">contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

CSS:

```
 nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 38px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 38px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  float: right;
}

nav li {
  height: 38px;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

nav a {
  height: 22px;
  padding: 16px 16px 0px 16px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: #16222f;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
}

nav a:hover {
  background: #ff4e00;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
}
```

Current results: http://jsfiddle.net/acy5p/

I will be glad to any advice.

Comment: I don't understand well what you want to achieve

Comment: I don't know what you want to know. You have to be more specific than 'I have a problem'.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Maybe my question wasn't formulated well, but solution is quite simple (by Marinus).
It's my fault - I had read too much information and it mixed up in my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I have changed your css hope it is what you are looking for..

```
  /*Menu*/
    nav {
      position: relative;
      top: 38px;
      right: 0px;
      height: 58px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      float: right;
        vertical-align:bottom;
    }
    nav li {
      height: 38px;
      float: left;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin-left: 1px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    nav a {
      height: 22px;
      padding: 16px 16px 0px 16px;
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      background: #16222f;
      border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
    }
    li a:hover {
      background: #ff4e00;
      border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
        margin-top: -10px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
        top:-10px;
    }
```

jsfiddle.net/acy5p/1 look at this fiddle...